# Creating Cases Object Automatically Based on Current Date

Tags: apex, workflow, process-builder, case, automation

I am attempting to set up logic that will run and create a Salesforce case if the current date equals either June 1st or October 1st.  I've been looking at process builder as one solution, but am struggling to find a way to set it to look at the current date instead of a relative date.  My other option I believe would be to create a custom Apex class and schedule it to run on those dates, however there is other criteria that must be met as well for these cases to be created and I'm not fluent enough with Apex enough to do this.

Does anyone have any ideas of what the best way to go about this would be?

Comment: Hi Leah, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post more details of the other criteria you need to consider or what you've tried so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you. Without that, your question would be considered too broad for our Forum and likely will be voted for closure.

Comment: There are declarative solutions to do this, but it can't be done with Process Builder alone. You may need an additional app like Mass Action Scheduler, to use Scheduled Apex, or to build an elaborate system of time-dependent actions keyed against your data. More detail in your question will help select a solution.

Comment: Also, how your are going to invoke this? - after manipulation of any record/object or irrespective to any record update? Because process builder would work mostly when any data manipulation takes place.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, without getting in to code, you need a process builder and flow. The process builder runs on a time delay based on custom object that has a date field. The flow creates a new entry for the next appropriate trigger date, and evaluates any other logic you need (e.g. creating cases). It's the custom object that provides the recurring timer for execution. To start the process, simply create a new custom object record to enqueue the next action. To cancel it, simply delete the latest record.

Note that this solution may fail if you need more than a few hundred cases all at once, in which case your only real solution is going to be Apex code. Even then, the Apex code would take less time, probably even if you have to learn it from the ground up.